# Creating a system user in Debian without home directory still creates a non-existent home directory entry in /etc/passwd

Tags: useradd

I'm trying to create a system user in Debian, with no home directory, for use with `getmail`.

Even though I did:

```
adduser --system --group --no-create-home getmail
```

The entry in `/etc/passwd` is:

```
getmail:x:122:156::/home/getmail:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

even though the `/home/getmail` directory is never created. Why mention a directory that was never created? I was expecting to see the placeholder `/nonexistent` there, which appears in several entries in `/etc/passwd`.

Why is the `/home/getmail` entry made, and if I want the `/nonexistent` entry instead, do I have to state it explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/nonexistent` is [mandated by Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#non-existent-home-directories), but that’s only relevant for packages in Debian. Lintian (the Debian QA tool) checks for invocations of `adduser --system` without `--home` (see [#730456](https://bugs.debian.org/730456) and [the `maintainer-script-lacks-home-in-adduser` tag](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/maintainer-script-lacks-home-in-adduser)).

Whether `adduser --system` should default to `/nonexistent` is the matter [of some debate](https://bugs.debian.org/679746), but there doesn’t seem to have been much discussion in the last decade.

> Why is the `/home/getmail` entry made, and if I want the `/nonexistent` entry instead, do I have to state it explicitly?

The answer to the former appears to be “for historical reasons”, and the answer to the latter is yes,

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --home /nonexistent ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, though the current default behavior is... untidy, at best. It should be changed, IMO.

Comment: It probably should; the only remaining concern is the effect such a change would have on any local administration scripts.

Comment: Use case: I have a directory `/home/someone` restored from a backup and I want to (re)create a user account to use it. What would you suggest in this situation, @FaheemMitha?

Comment: @roaima Is that relevant? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: @roaima presumably that wouldn’t be a system account, would it?

Comment: In the specific case, no, but I'm failing to see the significant difference here between a system account and a user account. I'm trying to understand why the existing behaviour is any more wrong than an alternative. We could, if you prefer, consider the "dovecot" system account and a restored mail spool

Comment: @roaima the difference I see is that for a user account you generally want a `/home/foo` directory, and the default provided by `adduser` is fine for most users (and `adduser.conf` provides configuration to cover some other scenarios). For a system account you either don’t want a home directory, or you want to specify it and it’s not a directory under `/home`. Even for scenarios such as the Dovecot mail spool, `dovecot`’s home directory isn’t the spool so it doesn’t matter much, but I don’t think you’d ever want `/home/dovecot`.

Comment: The concern here is that `adduser` does the right thing by default in most cases for user accounts, but `adduser --system` has a default which is never useful.

Comment: @StephenKitt A related question. Given that the `/etc/passwd` entry has a home entry that doesn't exist, it is safe to replace `/home/getmail` (in my case) with `/nonexistent` by directly editing the `/etc/passwd` file? I could delete and recreate the user, but I'm wary of complications (like if `adduser` doesn't recreate the user and group with the same ids) and if I can directly edit, that seems like the simplest option. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes, that is safe.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you for the confirmation.